# A generic error occurred in GDI+ after uploading

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I use this code for resize images on my web mvc it works good on my vs 2012 but when i upload it on server this error happen to me:

> A generic error occurred in GDI+.]
>   System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder,
>   EncoderParameters encoderParams) +811245    Utilty.CompressImage(Image
>   img, String path, ImageComperssion ic) +431

```
     public static void ResizeImage(this Stream inputStream, int width, int height, string savePath, ImageComperssion ic = ImageComperssion.Normal)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image img = new Bitmap(inputStream);
            System.Drawing.Image result = new Bitmap(width, height, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(result))
            {
                g.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                g.DrawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
            }
            result.CompressImage(savePath, ic);
        }

public static void CompressImage(this System.Drawing.Image img, string path, ImageComperssion ic)
    {
        System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, Convert.ToInt32(ic));
        ImageFormat format = img.RawFormat;
        ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders().FirstOrDefault(c => c.FormatID == format.Guid);
        string mimeType = codec == null ? "image/jpeg" : codec.MimeType;
        ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = null;
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders();
        for (int i = 0; i < codecs.Length; i++)
        {
            if (codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType)
            {
                jpegCodec = codecs[i];
                break;
            }
        }
        EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
        encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
        img.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
    }
```

Comment: As far as I know, there is no `CompressImage` method on the [`Image`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image(v=vs.110).aspx) class, which means it is likely an extension method, the `Utility.CompressImage` method. Since the stack is inside of that method, can you share the source for that?

Comment: Make Sure That your destination folder have read/write permission

Comment: I edit question and attach compress function

Comment: Did you checked there is a jpeg codec? (jpegCodec != null)

Answer (score 2):

1. Make Sure That your destination folder have **read/write** permission and you have free space on the destination drive
2. Make sure your hosted provider allow you to use `Memory Streamers` On their Shared Servers. most of the time they dont.